# yii, Development and URL issues

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii

We have our server which runs the site at 173......54/

For development we want to have a copy of the code that can be tested at 173.....54/~me/site

When I install a copy of Yii  and the code at ~me/ folder and access 173.....54/~me/site I am able 
to see the newly installed index html. However, if I try to move to 173.....54/~me/site/book or a user register page or any other page the other (main) Yii application reads the code as a link not found instead of the development Yii application.

Am I supposed to update a the htaccess file to ignore requests within /~me ? If so how should it look? Or am I missing something?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make ignore in other .htaccess, the dev site .htaccess will take care of it. 
 In your index.php at the root of your dev site you need to point $yii at your Yii framework/yii.php

and then in the .htaccess in the root of your dev site you need to point RewriteBase to your dev site root.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you point to the correct configuration file corresponding with your application in index.php

Comment: the line in the standard index file: `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';`  should automatically take care of that